# Unit test function in React / Jest with proper coverage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to test this toggle function with proper coverage in React / Jest:

```
    const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState<boolean>(true);
    const handlePush = () => setToggle(toggle => !toggle);

it ('Should test the handleClick method for toggling', () => {
    const handlePush = jest.fn(toggle => !toggle);
    let tree = create(<button onClick={handlePush}>Menu</button>)
    const button = tree.root.findByType('button')
    button.props.onClick()
    expect(handlePush).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

This passes but the coverage still does not cover the handlePush() method? any idea's?

Comment: Can you show the test result with coverage report?

Comment: Test result passes the coverage report highlights this function: `const handlePush= () => setToggle(toggle => !toggle);` in red as not covered